# Cannot Install Apple Turi Create

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda, turi-create

While installing [Turicreate](https://github.com/apple/turicreate) using `pip` on my macOS it gave me an error,

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement turicreate (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for turicreate
```

I did the following steps:

```
conda create -n venv python=2.7 anaconda
source activate venv
pip install -U turicreate
pip install --upgrade pip
```

> `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you create your `venv` virtual environment with `python=2.7`, the message you get when trying to upgrade `pip` indicates that you are running it in Python 3.5; the path

```
./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

clearly refers to the base Anaconda installation, and not to your `venv` virtual environment.

Given that, the error message you get is not unexpected, since Turicreate is [not yet available](https://github.com/apple/turicreate#system-requirements) for Python 3.5:

> ### System Requirements
>
> - Python 2.7 (Python 3.5+ support coming soon)
> - x86_64 architecture